# Question Gets Duplicated on a Different Q&A Site

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

My question gets cloned or duplicated on a different Q&A Site (not a different SE Site).

---

#### Question: No Microphone on CM12.1

Here's the [Original Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165449/no-microphone-on-cm12-1), while here's the [copy](http://www.resdi.com/62987/no-microphone-on-cm12-1).

It copied the exact same thing of my question / post, as well as the tags and the formattings; but it did not copy the edit / update and the comments (I can see no button there, to add a comment).

---

Thankfully, I searched / looked up my Question's Title.

Upon looking at the site, it appears that they are also duplicating many other questions on SE (separated by  categories, located at the side / sidebar).

Its welcome message says: (located at the upper part of the sidebar)

> Welcome to Resdi Community, where you can ask questions and receive answers from other members of the community.

But, I did not post that on their "community", and I am not a member of their community.  I only post questions on Stack Exchange.

I don't know if this is proper / right / legal, but they gave a credit to me.  They had put this:

> asked Dec 29, 2016 in Android by Lloyd Dominic

But, what they don't give credit is that "This question came from Stack Exchange", or "This question is a copy of a question on Stack Exchange", or something similar to that ...

Like I said, is this proper / right / legal?

Comment: Oh, okay!  Didn't know about that, 'cause this is my first post on Meta Stack Exchange.  I also don't know **SCRAPER**s yet ...